# Warning in the implementation of queue of AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, xcode, avcapturesession

i get a warning in the line as:

> (sending "ViewController *const_strong' to parameter of incompatible
>   type 'id'

When implementing this line of code

```
[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
```

Code used to handle queue

```
 [[selfcaptureSession]addOutput:output];
dispatch_queue_t queue =dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [outputsetSampleBufferDelegate:selfqueue:queue];
dispatch_release(queue);
```

Can anyone point out the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to the warning
The delegate property is typed as id. But self is not.
When using ARC we must make the cast explicit, so that the types formally agree.

So solution would be adding (id)self

```
[output setSampleBufferDelegate:(id)self queue:queue];
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Guess it should be:

```
[outputsetSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
```

But I don't think the problem is there or else it wouldn't work whatsoever. The warning is self explicit, you are sending the `ViewController` to a parameter of the type `id`. Could you show the signature of the method?

Comment: Yes, But still the warning continues! :(